# Shortest path that visit all vertices of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a undirected graph how can I find the shortest path that visits all vertices and return to the starting point? Repetition is allowed.

Is there a name for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If repetition is not allowed, then it is the [Hamiltonian cycle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) which is NP complete (i.e. probably hard to solve).

If you allow repetitions, then it is still at least as hard as the Hamiltonian cycle problem. If a Hamiltonian cycle exists, then this would be the shortest possible cycle (path which returns to its starting vertex). So we still have to check whether one exists, and this is NP complete.

Comment: Yes, I knew that when a Hamiltonian path is possible it is the solution. I was wondering if I find the path (without repetition) that visit the highest amount of vertices and than link the path to the ramaining vertices, would I have the better solution?

Comment: @RafaelMarinho This might depend on how exactly you "link the path to the remaining vertices". I can imagine that this might not necessarily give the best solution with repetitions, but not sure. However, even finding the longest possible non-repeating cycle is already NP complete.